# Does a singleton need to be refreshed with data from webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, singleton

I have a singleton provider, where the main function is to retrieve an object from a webservice, and cache depending on the webservice cache headers response. This object will be accessed quite a lot. My question is when the data in the webservice changes, will any subsequent call to the singleton automatically be reflected?

```
public class ConfigurationProvider
{
    #region Private Member Variables
    private static readonly Lazy<ConfigurationProvider> _instance = new Lazy<ConfigurationProvider>(() => new ConfigurationProvider());
    private static readonly HttpCache _cache = new HttpCache(); 
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    private ConfigurationProvider()
    {

    } 
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties
    public static ConfigurationProvider Instance
    {
        get { return _instance.Value; }
    }

    public ShowJsonResponse Configuration
    {
        get
        {
            // Try and get the configurations from webservice and add to cache
            var cacheExpiry = 0;
            return _cache.GetAndSet(WebApiConstant.ProxyCacheKeys.ShowJsonKey, ref cacheExpiry, () => GetConfiguration(ref cacheExpiry));
        }
    } 
    #endregion

    #region Private Methods
    private ShowJsonResponse GetConfiguration(ref int cacheExpiry)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        try
        {
            var response = httpClient.GetAsync(WebApiConstant.Configuration.WebserviceUrl).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var showResponse = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ShowJsonResponse>().Result;

                if (response.Headers.CacheControl.Public && response.Headers.CacheControl.MaxAge.HasValue)
                {
                    cacheExpiry = response.Headers.CacheControl.MaxAge.Value.Seconds;
                }

                // TODO: Remove when finished testing
                // Default to 60 seconds for testing
                cacheExpiry = 20;
                return showResponse;
            }

        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {

        }

        cacheExpiry = 0;
        return null;
    } 
    #endregion
}
```

The HttpCache class is just a wrapper around HttpRuntime Cache. The GetAndSet method just tries to retrieve the cache object and sets it if not found.

```
public override T GetAndSet<T>(string key, ref int duration, Func<T> method)
    {
        var data = _cache == null ? default(T) : (T) _cache[key];

        if (data == null)
        {
            data = method();

            if (duration > 0 && data != null)
            {
                lock (sync)
                {
                    _cache.Insert(key, data, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(duration), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
                }
            }
        }

        return data;
    }
```

Usage example:

```
ConfigurationProvider.Instance.Configuration.Blah
```

Is there any perceived benefit to using the singleton pattern in this scenario, or instantiate the class regularly would be ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the singleton pattern fits better in your case, and you won't need the object instance as well. Are you taking care of concurrency inside your HttpCache wrapper? It's important in order to avoid that concurrent threads could make multiple WS requests when two or more access the cache object at the same time or before the WS request returns.

I would suggest you to use the double lock/check pattern:

```
public override T GetAndSet<T>(string key, ref int duration, Func<T> method) {
    var data = _cache == null ? default(T) : (T) _cache[key];

    if (data == null) { //check
        lock (sync) { //lock

            //this avoids that a waiting thread reloads the configuration again
            data = _cache == null ? default(T) : (T) _cache[key];
            if (data == null) { //check again
                data = method();

                if (duration > 0 && data != null) {                 
                    _cache.Insert(key, data, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(duration), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: I've edited my original post to include the GetAndSet method.

Comment: I've written a suggestion to your GetAndSet method, but sorry, I couldn't test it here, because I'm in a Mac OS right now.